# can't type more than 48 characters in android studio terminal

Tags: android-studio, terminal

On my android studio terminal, if I type more than 48 characters they become invisible.

Android:1.1.0, Build number: AI:135.1740770

Comment: Any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Changing file-encoding to UTF-8, had solved the problem of characters not appearing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with Windows, the Android Studio windows needs to be in a "normal" state and not "maximized". It is a problem with Window's scaling. You're window in "normal" state is when your application can be resized with your cursor. Best you can do is just slightly resize the left or right edges and your terminal characters should appear...

Comment: If you are using cmd.exe as the terminal (You can confirm in File->Settings->Tools->Terminal) then perhaps you may have to increase the buffer that it displays. Open a regular terminal window anywhere on your computer and right click the top of the window and click "defaults". Under the "Layout" tab, you may change the Screen Buffer Size. I usually set mine to 800 width 600 height. After that press OK and then try the resize trick.